# Deriving Iteration Formula for $y''(x)=(3x^2+x^6)y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

As stated in the question I want to derive a iteration formula for the second order differential equation.

All I have been working with so far is the general Picard-iteration formula:

$$y_{n+1}(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y_n(t))dt \space \space \space \text{} \space \space \space y_0(x)=y_0$$

I thought this was some sort of fixed algorithm that one can use to derive some a taylor-series. How can I derive my "own" algorithm for the differential equation mentioned above?

Edit 1:

I am not sure if this is correct but I thought about just integreating the differential equation twice:

$$\begin{aligned}& y''(x)=(3x^2+x^6)y(x) \\ &y'(x)=\int (3x^2+x^6)y(x) dx+v_0 \\ &\boxed{y(x)=\color{red}{\int\int(3x^2+x^6)y(x)dxdx}+v_0x+y_0}\end{aligned}$$

I have no idea how to evaluate or simplify the red integral or if this is even the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By partial integration, you can show that
\begin{align}
y(x)&=y(a)+\int_a^x y'(s)ds\\
&=y(a)+y'(a)(x-a)+\int_a^x(x-s)y''(s)ds\\
&=y(a)+y'(a)(x-a)+\int_a^x(x-s)f(s,y(s))\,ds
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you maybe expand your answer a little bit. I have been trying to figure it out but I can't really see how you got this formula.